# How do I connect DBeaver to CockroachDB Serverless?

Tags: dbeaver, cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

How do I connect DBeaver with my CockroachDB Serverless database? I get errors that look like this:

```
FATAL: codeParamsRoutingFailed: missing cluster name in connection string
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure to include the cluster name in the database field.

The database should be something like: `cluster-name-1234.databasename`.

Here is a screenshot of a working configuration:

[image]

Comment: The cluster name, including the tenant id, is available from the "connect" modal in the options text box (it is the --cluster value).

Answer (score 1):

To find the cluster name, including the tenant id use the Connect modal from the CockroachCloud Database Page:

[image: Connect Modal]

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, include `.defaultdb` to the end of the name of your database in the "Database" field. For example, `databasename-dev-369.defaultdb`

This was the least intuitive config detail, easily killed an hour of my time :/  Hope this helps.

Comment: This was the detail I was missing!